# Many-to-many multi-database join with Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to make this many-to-many join work with Flask-SQLAlchemy and two MySQL databases, and it's very close except it's using the wrong database for the join table. Here's the basics...

I've got `main_db` and `vendor_db`. The tables are setup as `main_db.users`, `main_db.user_products` (the relation table), and then `vendor_db.products`. Should be pretty clear how those are all connected.

in my app.py, I'm seting up the databases like this:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://user:pass@localhost/main_db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = {
        'vendor_db': 'mysql://user:pass@localhost/vendor_db'
}
```

Model definitions are set up like this:

```
from app import db

# Setup relationship
user_products_tbl = db.Table('user_products', db.metadata,
        db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.user_id')),
        db.Column('product_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('products.product_id'))
)

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    products = db.relationship("Product", secondary=user_products_tbl,
            backref="users", lazy="dynamic")

class Product(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'vendor_db'
    __tablename__ = 'products'
    id = db.Column('product_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120))
```

The problem is that when I try to get a user's products it's trying to use `vendor_db` for the join table instead of `main_db`. Any ideas how I can make it use `main_db` instead? I've tried setting up another bind to `main_db` and setting `info={'bind_key': 'main_db'}` on the relationship table definition, but no luck. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out what I needed to do here was specify the schema in my `user_products_tbl` table definition. So,

```
user_products_tbl = db.Table('user_products', db.metadata,
        db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.user_id')),
        db.Column('product_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('products.product_id')),
        schema='main_db'
)
```

Hope this helps someone else!